# Spacemacs mode commands give error in projectile

Tags: r, spacemacs, ess, projectile, emacs-projectile

When I try to run mode commands (such as "start Repl", "send buffer") in ESS(R) mode in Spacemacs within a projectile, I get the following error:

"No applicable method: project-roots (projectile [projectile root location])"

When I handle R-files outside a projectile everything works fine. I am aware that my issue is related to:
-https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/2335

-https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/1052

But I fail to extract a concrete instruction on what I can do to fix the issue. A workaround would be fine. Adding the code

```
(setq ess-gen-proc-buffer-name-function 'ess-gen-proc-buffer-name:directory)
(setq ess-use-flymake nil)
```

to dotspacemacs/user-config, as I think was suggested in the first issue, did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pulling the newest Spacemacs (development branch) and updating all packages solved it for me.